# how to achieve constant and precise time sync among hosts?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ntp

Hi I need micro second level time synchronisation within a group of systems, But I found it difficult.

**My experiment:** in a LAN, constantly comparing 2 x64 linux system hardware time clocks between via some ruby code: which is using udp packets to send microseocond timestamp to the other and comparing the difference. experiment code: https://github.com/c2h2/chrono-diff

**Results:** The time drift quickly! Interestingly they are also not drifting within one direction, the difference of two clocks is sometimes positive, sometimes negative, random manner. And they might differ as apart as 1 second after several hours from pervious sync.

How should I keep the perfectly sync'ed all the time? run time sync every several minutes?

Answer (score 0):

setup one of the host as ntp server and let the other host use that server  as ntp server. 
http://www.ntp.org/documentation.html